# Refresh datagridview records from another form

Tags: c#, sql, select, datagridview, refresh

I have `dataGridView1` in `form1` but for inserting in it I'm using `form2` which have save button (that provides insert into datagridview1) to which I'm trying to set - `refresh` or `select * from` so I dont need any refresh button in `form1` whenever I want to show up just all the recors. Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use delegate.. For example :

Form1 :

```
private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

// Create an instance of form 2
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();

    // Create an instance of the delegate
    form2.passControl = new Form2.PassControl(PassData);

    // Show form 2
    form2.Show();
}

private void PassData(object sender)
{
    // Set de text of the textbox to the value of the textbox of form 2
    txtForm1.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

Form 2 :

```
public class Form2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    // Define delegate
    public delegate void PassControl(object sender);

    // Create instance (null)
    public PassControl passControl;

    private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (passControl != null)
        {
            passControl(txtForm2);
        {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: I'm not sure If i can use this, I have already save button in form2 connected to sql DB and this button also inserts into database

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Form.DialogResult` to achieve this.

In your insert form, after saving data to database:

```
DbContext.SaveChanges();
MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved.");
DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
```

and In your grid form:

```
Frm_NewData newData = new Frm_NewData();
if (newData.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
     RefreshGrid();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but with what should I replace in form2 (which inserts into DB) the DbContext? it gives me error "The name "DbContext" does not exist in the current context."

Comment: You should replace `DbContext.SaveChanges();` line with your save to DB code block. :-)